# How to update a model in the Database with Django Rest Framwork Serializer fails?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I run my code at the first time, it works successfully. Data are stored in the database and the http code is 200. If I change some data on the client side and try to save the model again, I reach the following error.

I read on the django doc, hat i can use Save as "create" and "update" as well.

**error message**

```
heating mapping with this zone already exists
```

**views.py**

```
from heatingControll.models import  HeatingMapping as HeatingMappingModel
 # ... some code ...
    @detail_route(methods="post")
    def save(self, request):
        zone = request.data.get('zone')
        data = json.loads(zone)

        serializer = HeatingMappingSerializer(data=data)

        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if(valid):
           result = serializer.save()
           self.response = {"result": True, "data":HeatingMappingSerializer(result).data, "message": "Erfolgreich gespeichert"}

        return JsonResponse(self.response, safe=False)
```

**SOLUTION supported by zaidfazil**

@detail_route(methods="post")
def save(self, request):
    zone = request.data.get('zone')
    data = json.loads(zone)

```
if 'zone' in data:
    obj = HeatingMappingModel.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
    serializer = HeatingMappingSerializer(data=data, instance=obj)
else:
    serializer = HeatingMappingSerializer(data=data)

valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
if(valid):
   result = serializer.save()
   self.response = {"result": True, "data":HeatingMappingSerializer(result).data, "message": "Erfolgreich gespeichert"}

return JsonResponse(self.response, safe=False)
```

Comment: Show your models please?.... The first time.., you are creating an instance, the second time.., you think you are updating the same instance, but you are not. You are just creating another instance.

Comment: Could you show your entire view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your view maybe like this,

```
@detail_route(methods="post")
def save(self, request, pk):
    zone = request.data.get('zone')
    data = json.loads(zone)
    obj = HeatingMapping.objects.get(pk=pk)

    serializer = HeatingMappingSerializer(data=data, instance=obj)

    valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    if(valid):
       result = serializer.save()
       self.response = {"result": True, "data":HeatingMappingSerializer(result).data, "message": "Erfolgreich gespeichert"}

    return JsonResponse(self.response, safe=False)
```

Comment: well thank you for your fast reply, support and very good input to find the solution. It works. I've posted my solution into my question. in case you wanna know it. I have found a other way but based on your solution.